# How to define to type that comprise each other

Tags: ocaml

I am using ocaml to build a simple compiler for bean. In bean each type definition consists of

1. the keyword 'typedef',
2. a type specification,
3. an identifier.

A type specification in any one of :

1.the keywords 'bool' or 'int'

2.a comma-separated list of field definitions surrounded by { and }

3.an identifier

I want to define two type like this  :

```
type field_def = (ident * typespec)

type typespec =
  | Bool 
  | Int
  | Tident of ident
  | Tfield_def of field_def list

type typedef = (ident * typespec)
```

I use type in the definition of field_def but define it in the next definition,so there will always appears the type unbound error. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to create types that depend on each other, you must use `and`:

```
type a = A | OfB of b
and b = B | OfA of a
```

It's the same as when you want to define mutually recursive functions:

```
let rec is_even n = n = 0 || is_odd (n - 1)
and is_odd n = n <> 0 && is_even (n - 1)
```